# How to do this non linear least square fitting that involves an integral?

Tags: matlab

I have the following expression:

phi=(a)*int(exp(-x*(1+(8*pi*b*c)^2))dx), 
where the integral is from 0 to inf, and a,b,c are constants.

I know phi, but I do not know the constants a,b and c. That is why I want to do a non linear least square fitting, as I am not sure I will obtain a straight line, in case of obtaining it I would change it.

The thing is that I think I have problems with defining the integral and introducing it in the final expression where I do the non linear least square fitting. Loads of errors appear once I run it.

The code is the following:

```
%I introduce the data
qy=[0.022 0.023 0.025 0.027 0.028 0.03 0.033 0.037 0.043 0.049 0.058 0.065 0.075 0.094 0.141 0.155 0.192 0.219 0.369];

QY=qy(end);
%I introduce initial guesses for my fitting
initial_guesses=[max(max(qy))/2  QY/10 max(max(qy))/2];
i_g(1,1)=initial_guesses(1,1);
i_g(2,1)=initial_guesses(1,2);
i_g(3,1)=initial_guesses(1,3);

%Let's define my integral
fun=@(x,parameters) exp(-x.*(1+(8*pi()*parameters(2)*parameters(3)).^2));

%We model the fitting
HoffForst_decaydiff=@(parameters) (qy(1:end)-parameters(1)*integral(@(x,parameters)fun,0,Inf));

%options = optimoptions(@lsqnonlin,'Algorithm','levenberg-marquardt');
options = optimoptions(@lsqnonlin,'Algorithm','levenberg-marquardt','TolFun',1e-7,'TolX',1e-7);

%perform NL LS fit
[fit_parameters, resnorm, fit_residuals]=lsqnonlin(HoffForst_decaydiff, i_g, [], [], options);
```

The errors that appear once I run the last line (lsqnonlin line) are:
Error using integralCalc/finalInputChecks (line 511)
Input function must return 'double' or 'single' values. Found 'function_handle'.

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 315)
                finalInputChecks(x,fx);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 83)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AToInfInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 88)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);

Error in @(parameters)(qy(1:end)-parameters(1)*integral(@(x,parameters)fun,0,Inf))

Error in lsqnonlin (line 194)
            initVals.F = feval(funfcn{3},xCurrent,varargin{:});

Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. LSQNONLIN cannot continue.

Can you help me, please?

Cheers!

Comment: When you define `HoffForst_decaydiff` you should just have `integral(fun,0,inf)` not `integral(@(x,parameters)fun,0,Inf)`.

Comment: @PhilGoddard I don't think that's the problem because fun should take a single input argument and the way his function handle is defined it takes two. I think the call should look like `integral(@(x)fun(x,parameters),0,Inf)`

Comment: @RandomGuy, yes I think you're right.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks a lot for your answers. It worked but now I realised I need to introduce another vector and I am having again problems. I am trying to sort it out but without any success.
This time the new vector is called 'viscosity', so I want to do this integral for each viscosity value.
My code is the following:
 `%Let's define my integral
    fun=@(x,parameters) exp(-x-(x.^3).*(parameters(2)./viscosity(1:end)).^2);
    %We model the fitting
    HoffForst_decaydiff=@(parameters) (qy(1:end)-parameters(1)*integral(@(x)fun(x,parameters),0,Inf));`

Loads of errors... any idea?